# Ember component send action to route

Tags: ember.js

I have two component and one sitting on another. I need to send an event to main route from child component( both components use in same route)

[image]

Please let me know is there any standard way to do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For short answer you can you can use [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) addon.

```
<button {{action (route-action 'onButtonClick')}}>ClickToCallRouteAction</button>
```

There are three way of actions communication,

**1. Old style classic functions style** ie., passing function name as string from top to bottom. and in all the places we need to define same function and provide. Use `sendAction` to bubble. and `send` method bubble from controller to route hierarchy.

This is not encouraged.
Sample classic style [actions twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f88f37df35e93a89eca29c8340517cb2?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

**2. Closure actions**
Use `action` helper pass function instead of just string. so that you don't need to define it everywhere.
[sample twiddle for closure actions](https://ember-twiddle.com/93e1e5e72f008b013636275b6f26ba3f?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) style

**3. [route-action-helper addon](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper)**
You can directly call route action from anywhere literally by just wrapping functions using `route-action` helper.

[Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6c9daed104eb669f3d4ea49169ab5891?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2C)

**Comparision between Classic style and Closure style and Why Closure is preferrable ?**

- In classic style, You need to define actions at each level and use sendAction to trigger the action at each level until you got all the way out of your nesting.
- You can return value in closure actions but not in classic actions.
- You can curry values in closure actions but not in classic actions.
- Closure actions fail immediately if the action is not found. but classic actions by design,would lazily raise errors only upon invocation
  values.
- Coding complexity like who will handle actions and do business logic?.
- In closure, you can combine action and mut helper to set a property with value. `onclick=(action (mut title) value="titlevalue")`
- In closure, you can specify target object to invoke function. `(action 'save' target=session)` would look at the `actions` hash on the `session` object instead of the current context.

**Some of the promising article regarding this,**
- miguelcamba article [ember-closure-actions-in-depth](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/)
- emberigniter article [send-closure-actions-up-data-owner](https://emberigniter.com/send-closure-actions-up-data-owner/)
- emberjs blog [1.13 release article](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions)
- dockyard - [ember-best-practice-stop-bubbling-and-use-closure-actions](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/29/ember-best-practice-stop-bubbling-and-use-closure-actions)
- blog from Ember map [Why action helper?](https://embermap.com/notes/26-a-note-on-actions)
- blog from Alisdair McDiarmid [ember-closure-actions-have-return-values](https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-closure-actions-have-return-values/)
- blog from alexdiliberto [ember-closure-actions](https://alexdiliberto.com/posts/ember-closure-actions/)

Comment: Why *old style classic functions style* is not encouraged? Can you elaborate more between the difference between (1) and (2).

Comment: @LiXinyang Updated difference and why closure is preferred and along with some good article.

Comment: Thanks for your time @kumkanillam. Upvoted! +10 All these reference are greats

Comment: Love you @kumkanillam This closure action twiddle save my day and probably a lot of hours of research how to do that.

Comment: Great answer, thank you @kumkanillam . References are superb, thank you. Would upvote x10 if I could.

Comment: OMGTYVM, this saved my life! I was using the option nr. 1 (Old school classic functions style). Took the twiddle as an example for my implementation, and it works on Ember 1.8.1 app. Spent over a day finding solution...

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ember 3.14, [Octane](https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/), we can solve this problem in a modern, explicit, concise and clear way -- which we'll get to after this brief intermission:

> I need to send an event to main route from child component

While this is *possible*, it's strongly recommended against, as Routes should not have actions and should be stateless. That said, we can solve the problem of action passing through deep components in a couple of ways:

- ["Data Down, Actions Up"](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/readers-questions-what-is-meant-by-the-term-data-down-actions-up/15311)
- Use a Service

For the first, Data Down, Actions Up, you may pass arguments down as many component layers as you desire

```
// app/controllers/application.js:
@action
dance(){
  console.log('┏(-_-)┓┏(-_-)┛┗(-_- )┓')
}

// app/templates/application.hbs
<Foo @dance={{this.dance}} />

// app/components/foo.hbs
<Bar @dance={{@dance}} />

// app/components/bar.hbs
<button {{on 'click' @dance}}>Dance!</button>
```

This could be a slipperly slope. While only having two components to data down, and to *action* back up (after a click in this case), it may not seem like too much effort, but many UIs could be 10+ components deep, and would lend themselves to an anti-pattern known as [Prop-Drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling).

To mitigate *prop-drilling*, we have another approach in our toolbox to reach for. Services!

```
// app/services/my-service.js
@action
dance(){
  console.log('┏(-_-)┓┏(-_-)┛┗(-_- )┓')
}

// app/components/bar.js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class Bar extends Component {
  @service myService;
}

// app/components/bar.hbs
<button {{on 'click' this.myService.dance}}>Dance!</button>
```

The deeply nested component can access the action directly, rather than needing to be passed through a few layers -- this leads to much more maintainable and clear code.

**Resources**

- [Classic to Octane Cheat Sheet](https://ember-learn.github.io/ember-octane-vs-classic-cheat-sheet/)
- [Octane Edition Documentation Page](https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/)

Comment: !remindme 2 days: see if codesandbox is fixed, and provide a live working code sample

Comment: While this shows a great pattern, it doesn't answer the question at all. I stumbled upon this while trying to figure out how to invoke a built-in action (refresh) on a route if trying to avoid adding a controller + extra action + use of `sendAction` just for this one purpose. Seems to be a missing feature of the routing service.