# Using sendAction() to implement data down actions up pattern in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, action

I'm doing a little app to try and learn Ember.js, but I'm really struggling with the implementation of a data-down-actions-up component. For some reason I don't seem to be able to 'send' an action back up to the router properly. The component action is triggered when I want it to be, but the `sendAction()` doesn't seem to be doing anything.

My code is below:

My Component (editable-cell.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isEditing: false,
  startingText: "",
  saveAction: null,
  asdf: 'asdf jkl;',

  actions: {
    edit() {
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    cancelEdit() {
      this.set('isEditing', false);
    },
    save() {
      console.log("SAVE");

      // I'm using the 'asdf' property just as a placeholder for now to get it working.
      this.sendAction('action', this.get('asdf'));
      this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
  }
});
```

My Component Template (editable-cell.hbs):

```
<td>
  {{#if isEditing}}
    <form {{action 'saveAction' "Test Text" on='submit'}} class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" value="{{startingText}}">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" {{action 'cancelEdit'}}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  {{else}}
    <span {{action 'edit'}}>{{startingText}}</span>
  {{/if}}
</td>
```

My Template (books.hbs):

```
<h1>Books</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      Title
      <br><small class="small not-bold">(Click on name for editing)</small>
    </th>
    <th class="vtop">Author</th>
    <th class="vtop">Release Year</th>
    <th class="vtop">Library</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each model as |book|}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{editable-cell startingText=book.title action=saveBook}}
      </td>
      <td>{{book.author.name}}</td>
      <td>{{book.releaseYear}}</td>
      <td>{{book.library.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The Router (books.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('book');
  },
  actions: {
    saveBook: function(book) {
      console.log("In the book controller");
      console.log(book);
      book.save();
    }
  }
});
```

The Controller (books.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
});
```

Comment: `action=saveBook` should be `action=(action 'saveBook')` I think. But consider to go for closure actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using classic actions so action name should be passed as string. so this will do the trick `{{editable-cell startingText=book.title action='saveBook'}}`

Created twiddle with [minimum sample](https://ember-twiddle.com/b454b95b65218f460ab55e9949fbe1be?openFiles=templates.books.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.editable-cell.hbs)

Please have a look [ember component send action to route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296007/5771666) answer