# How to create action for my own component

Tags: ember.js

I am creating one ember app.
Flow is like " page1 displays list of feeds item and clicking on any of the feed will take user to page2 showing details about that feed"

**What i am doing:**
i have one component named app-feed. Template is as below

```
<div onclick={{action 'click' feed}}>
{{#paper-card class="card-small" as |card|}}
  <!--  <a href="feed/{{feed.id}}"> --> {{card.image src=feed.imagePath class="small-feed-img" alt=feed.title}}<!--</a>-->
    {{#card.header class="flex-box short-padding" as |header|}}
            {{#header.avatar}}
                <img class="profile-small"  src="http://app.com/users/{{feed.userName}}.jpg" alt="{{feed.name}}" />
            {{/header.avatar}}
            <span class="tag-sm like-box">
                {{feed.likes}} {{paper-icon "thumb_up" size="18"}}
                {{feed.commentCount}}{{paper-icon "chat_bubble"  size="18"}}
            </span>
    {{/card.header}}
    {{#card.actions class="action-block"}}
        {{#paper-button iconButton=true}}{{paper-icon "favorite" size="18"}}{{/paper-button}}
        {{#paper-button iconButton=true}}{{paper-icon "share" size="18"}}{{/paper-button}}
        {{#paper-button iconButton=true}}{{paper-icon "shopping_basket" size="18"}}{{/paper-button}}

    {{/card.actions}}
{{/paper-card}}
</div>
```

component.js is as below
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions:{
      click(feed){
        console.log("Click event fired:"+feed.id); //Output is correct in console
        this.sendAction("onClick", feed); //sending onClick Action
      }
    }
});
```

I'm populating list of this component in one of my route.
Template is as below

```
{{#app-sidenav user=model}}{{/app-sidenav}}
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
      {{#each model as |item|}}
        {{#app-feed-small onClick=(action "getDetail" item) class="col-xs-5" feed=item}} {{/app-feed-small}}
      {{/each}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

route.js is as below
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),

    model(){
        //Populating module. Works just fine
    } ,
    actions:{
      getDetails(feed){
        console.log("Getting details of "+feed.id);
      }
    }   
});
```

I have defined getDetails action as mentioned in my template.js of the route still i am getting below error

""Assertion Failed: An action named 'getDetail' was not found in (generated feed.index controller)""

feed.index is my route.

I used same method and modified paper-chip's source to get action corresponding to click on paper-chip's item which worked. But i am not able to do same in my own component.
Please let me know what is missing

Comment: Actions should be in controllers. If the corresponding controller bubbles up the action then the action in route called

Comment: I am using ember 2.11.0, i guess controller is deprecated in favor of component. Please Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No it's not deprecated. If you are using components so the actions should be there. But you want to handle the actions in (route). So you need controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your second last code snippet, the one with your template. You refer to the action as `getDetail` but in `route.js` your last code snippet you declare the action as `getDetails` which is different to the code in your template. It's a common spelling error, one has an "s" st the end whereas the other doesn't.

Comment: thx for quick reply. I corrected the spelling but nothing changed. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The actions should be in controllers. And if controller bubbles up then the action in route be called.

For your case you don't need controller.

You can use [ember-transition-helper](https://github.com/peec/ember-transition-helper)

I assume you have in `router.js` :

```
this.route('feeds', function(){
  this.route('edit', {path: '/:id'});
});
```

Now your template is going to be :

```
{#app-sidenav user=model}}{{/app-sidenav}}
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
      {{#each model as |item|}}
        {{#app-feed-small onClick=(transition-to "feeds.edit" item) class="col-xs-5" feed=item}} {{/app-feed-small}}
      {{/each}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendAction` is an ancient way to calling action inside controller/route.

The new style is to use closure action, which passes action as a value by creating a closure at the time of value passing.

Yes, you are correct. The action has been `sendAction` is able to bubble up from,

```
correspond controller -> correspond route -> upper route -> ... -> application route
```

However, closure action does NOT bubble.

Please refer to [Ember component send action to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295604/ember-component-send-action-to-route) where @kumkanillam detailed explained how to call action inside route using different method and the differences between `sendAction` and closure action.

I have also made a sample project and write a simple explanation for it at,

https://github.com/li-xinyang/FE_Ember_Closure_Action