# How to pass ember computed model data to nested component without querying?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have nested components. Every component has button to show its nested component.

From controller I pass selectbox options (query on store) through all components. But query is done before final component with selectbox is even shown/drawn. Real query its done at moment of when second component with this property is drawn.

Is there way to not do query till its really needed for selectbox to be drawn ? I did not wanted to have store property straight in nested component itself.

**EDITED**

As suggested by **kumkanillam**, his solution worked pretty well, here is code to get the idea.

In controler:

```
        reactionTimesForOptions: null,
        allReactionTimes: function() {
            return this.get("store").findAll("reaction-time");
        }.property("store"),
        actions:{
            initialiseRatingOptionsData(){
                if(Ember.isEmpty(this.get("reactionTimesForOptions"))) {
                    this.set("reactionTimesForOptions",  this.get("allReactionTimes"));
            }
        }
```

In controler hbs

```
{{#task-list 
    allReactionTimes=reactionTimesForOptions 
    initialiseRatingOptionsData=(action "initialiseRatingOptionsData")}
{{/task-list}}
```

Then in next 2 nested components

```
 allReactionTimes=allReactionTimes
 initialiseRatingOptionsData=initialiseRatingOptionsData
```

And finnaly at point of clicking and showing my component which need to have data from database, in component deciding on showing final component

```
toggleRatingScreen(){
    this.initialiseRatingOptionsData(); /* at this point query are done since needed only at this point*/
    ....
```

Comment: What do you mean by `computed model data` ? Are you referring to `selectbox options` ?

Comment: In controller like :

    allWorkQualities: function() {
        return this.get("store").findAll("work-quality");
    }.property("store"),

I guess i should remove "computed" word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass empty selectbox options property from controller along with function `updateSelectboxOptions` which will update `selectbox` options, and in nested component when you need to data you can just call  `updateSelectboxOptions`.

Comment: Oh thats an interesting idea, you mean with like "this.sendAction" to controller inside action called when button to show component with selectbox is clicked ?

Comment: yes. instead of `sendAction`  you can use closure action. you can follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42296007/5771666) for more info regarding closure action.

Comment: With closure action, can i return options array object, so i would need to only pass clojure action itself throught nested components ?

Comment: Yes. you can return. but nothing wrong in sending data all the way down

Comment: i did it that way, tnx much for help,  (also updated question)