# How to transition to the same route from a component in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have a main template say `showcountry.hbs` , inside that I am having a component `show-state.hbs`. In `show-state.js` I have tried putting `this.transitionTo('routename')` . I see that it works for routes other than `showcountry` . Complicating thing slightly is that in my `router.js`  the entry looks something like the following `this.route('showcountry' , {path : '/app/mod/country' });`

I find that in component when I give the URL pattern in `this.transitionTo` it throws unrecognized URL error .

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`transitionTo` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_transitionTo)  if you are in route.

[`transitionToRoute` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute) If you are in controller.

To transition to the same route, you can use [refresh method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh).
So to resolve issue, you need to send action from component to route to call refresh method.

Note: if route is already rendered, then you can't transition to the current route, but if you use [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) or [queryParams](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/routing/query-params/) then you can send that argument to transitionTo method which will call all the model hooks and re-render again.  [Sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9a839b38e03421e4bb9fec722c269ea7?openFiles=routes.a.js%2C) which demonstrate this

Comment: I don't have controllers in my application, and I don't want to add it also. Is it possible to demonstrate ur example with a transitionTo in a component?

Comment: Did you check with samle twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/9a839b38e03421e4bb9fec722c269ea7?openFiles=routes.a.js%2C in my answer, its not using controller.

Comment: By the way you can do it in component, but you shouldn't call transitionTo in component, you should send actions to route for this.

Comment: ok,so how will i invoke the refreshRoute from the component .

Comment: Here is the updated twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/9a839b38e03421e4bb9fec722c269ea7?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs which will invoke route refresh method from component

Comment: Hi, maybe i am being a noob , but i see that the acction from component is caught by controller and then controller invokes the action in route . Can this be bypassed

Comment: Yes. then you need to install [add on ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) to bypass. sample implementation would be use `(route-action` helper instead of `(action` and also call it like `this.get('actionName')();` : More explanation refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42296007/5771666

Comment: This worked , it invokes the beforeModel, but i was also expecting it to rerender the page  so that the afterrenderevent hook gets called. how can we do that?

Comment: Which afterrender event ? I dont get it. When we do refresh, entire dom will not be changed only the properties used in template will be changed and `{{#if` block and `{{#each` block dom element will be rendered again. not the whole DOM. you can create sample to twiddle to demonstrate your issue to us

Comment: I have updated the twiddle you had put. have added a new component my-comp1 . I would like the contents of my-comp1 to be executed each time refreshmodel() is called

Comment: twiddle link please

Comment: Its not showing your changes. You need to save and get link from share twiddle from File menu

Comment: apologies :(  [link twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/fe0eba953660b0812f9abead7bccdee8?openFiles=templates.a.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Comment: I updated with sample https://ember-twiddle.com/fe0eba953660b0812f9abead7bccdee8?openFiles=templates.a.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs In this twiddle you can see the properties changing when we do refresh. thats how it will work, it will not rewrite DOM for refresh. I would encourage you to read more on ember guides and  data down actions up related article .

Comment: i dont see the changes

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/f793af4f787645e411eca418b9d17355?openFiles=templates.a.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs