# how to call action of route from component?

Tags: ember.js

i have button in component

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" {{action "applyDateFilter"}}>GO</button>
```

Now i have written this action applyDateFilter in component.js like this

```
applyDateFilter() {
            var variable = this.get('dateFilter');
            this.sendAction('testAction2');
        }
```

Now i have another action in main route.js file

```
testAction2: function(){
            alert('test');
        }
```

Now i want to call this route action from applyDateFilter action so how can i do this.I am using ember js version 2.10.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1.You need to define action in controller, and use send method to call action in route.

```
testAction2(){
  this.send('testAction2Route');
}
```

option 2.Install [ember route action helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) addon. and you can invoke it directly from component like the below,

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" {{route-action "applyDateFilter"}}>GO</button>`

Note using route-action instead of usual action helper

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295604/ember-component-send-action-to-route/42296007#42296007) for classic action and closure action and route action related stuff