# Nothing handled the action 'deleteComment'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have 2 action handlers, updateComment and deleteComment, both climbing up to the route in exact the same way, yet updateComment works just fine, where deleteComment does not, giving the error 'Nothing handled the action 'deleteComment'.

Route:
Review.js

```
updateComment(comment, params) {
            Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
                if(params[key]!== undefined) {
                    comment.set(key,params[key]);
                }
            });
            comment.save();
        }
    },
    deleteComment(comment) {
                comment.destroyRecord();
        }
```

Review.hbs

```
{{comment-list
    loginId=model.loginId
    article=model.article
    user=model.user
    session=model.session
    updateComment="updateComment"
    deleteComment="deleteComment"
}}
```

Components: comment-list.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {

        updateComment(comment) {
            let params = {
                title: this.get('title')
            };
            this.sendAction('updateComment', comment, params);
        },
        deleteComment(comment) {
            this.sendAction('deleteComment', comment);
        }
    }
});
```

comment-list.hbs

```
    {{#each article.comments as |comment|}}
    {{comment-tile
            comment=comment
            user=user
            loginId=loginId
            updateComment="updateComment"
            deleteComment="deleteComment"

    }}
{{/each}}
```

comment-tile.js is exactly the same as comment-list.js.

comment-tile.hbs

```
            {{#if isAllowed}}
            {{comment-update
                    user=user
                    comment=comment
                    updateComment="updateComment"
            }}

            {{comment-delete
                    user=user
                    comment=comment
                    deleteComment="deleteComment"
            }}
        {{/if}}
```

comment-update.js + category-update.hbs

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    updateCommentForm: false,
    actions: {
        updateCommentForm() {
            this.set('updateCommentForm', true);
        },
        updateComment(comment) {
            let params = {
                title: this.get('title'),
                body: this.get('body'),
                score: this.get('score')
            };
            this.set('updateCommentForm', false);
            this.sendAction('updateComment', comment, params);
        }
    }

});

{{#if updateCommentForm}}
    <div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="titleupdate">Titel</label>
                {{input value=comment.title id="titleupdate"}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bodyupdate">Inhoud</label>
                {{input value=comment.body id="bodyupdate"}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="scoreupdate">Score</label>
                {{input value=comment.score id="scoreupdate"}}
            </div>

            <button class="btn-default" {{action 'updateComment' comment}}>Opslaan</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{{else}}
    <button class="btn-default btn-info" {{action 'updateCommentForm'}}>Aanpassen</button>
{{/if}}
```

comment-delete.js + comment-delete.hbs

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteComment(comment) {
            this.sendAction('deleteComment', comment);
        }
    }
});

<button class="btn-default btn-danger" {{action 'deleteComment' comment}}>Verwijderen</button>
```

It's the exact same code, just splitting up into 2 components at the end. I can't, for the life of me, work out why the delete action isn't working. When I changed the name from destroyComment to deleteComment, I worked my way down from route to deepest component and the error changed when I renamed the deepest component, so I'm guessing it goes wrong at the deepest level, but again, I really don't see why.

**EDIT 1:** Changed my code to closure actions, as suggested, but the same problem persists.

**EDIT 2:** In review.js,there was a curly brace missing on a higher level than the code I posted. actions:{} was closed after updateComment and before deleteComment, excluding the latter for use, but Webstorm didn't throw an error. This was the full code with the error:

```
    actions: {
    saveComment(params) {
        let newComment = this.store.createRecord('comment', params);

        let article = params.article;
        let user = params.user;
        article.get('comments').addObject(newComment);
        user.get('comments').addObject(newComment);
        newComment.save().then(function () {
            return article.save().then(function () {
                return user.save();
            });
        });
    },
    updateComment(comment, params) {
        Object.keys(params).forEach(function (key) {
            if (params[key] !== undefined) {
                comment.set(key, params[key]);
            }
        });
        comment.save();
    },
    deleteComment(comment) {
        comment.destroyRecord();
    }
//Here should have been another curly brace.
});
```

Comment: Your code is looking good to me. it should work as you expect.  my suggestion would be to use closure action for this kind of deep level actions. you can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295604/ember-component-send-action-to-route/42296007#42296007) for why?. if you could reproduce it in twiddle, it will help us to sort it out. You might stop and start ember server fresh.

Comment: I just changed it to closure actions with route-action-helper, and it's the exact same thing, lol. Update works fine with it, delete is a no-go. I'll try and make a fiddle that reproduces the error.

Comment: I found the solution. There was faulty code after all, which webstorm didn't notify me about. In review.js there's a curly brace short, so the actions curly brace closed itself after the update action, thus excluding the delete action. I only noticed it because I wanted to try one action handler at a time, and the moment I deleted updateComment, the error popped up. From the code I have posted, this error wasn't visible, I only included those 2 actions for brevity, confident that everything else was in order, but the error was at a higher level.

Comment: Glad you found it.

Comment: I added an edit with the faulty code, so you can witness my stupidity in all its glory. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In review.js,there was a curly brace missing on a higher level than the code I posted. actions:{} was closed after updateComment and before deleteComment, excluding the latter for use, but Webstorm didn't throw an error.

See code from EDIT 2 to gaze upon my stupidity in all its glory.