# Ember: Should I call transition from a controller or component

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering what the best practices around transition to another route in Ember. Currently in my controller, I call the ember data store then transition to another route using transitionToRoute function but with the new focus components these days I saw you an inject the router as a service inside your component. Is this where I should be moving this logic or controller is still right place for this?

Answer (score 5):

The best practice is to use `Route` for loading and mutating data as well as for transitions.  Remember: data down, actions up.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/

Answer (score 1):

Always best practice would be to use `route`. In case if you are forced to use transition in any other places may be in your smart component then you can use [ember-router-service-polyfill addon](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-router-service-polyfill).

```
ember install ember-router-service-polyfill
```

Then you can do inject `router` service and use `transitionTo` method.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  router: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    next() {
      this.get('router').transitionTo('other.route');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok there is piece of the puzzle I am missing... I have template with button component on it:  {{x-button label="Test" action=(action "testButton")}} that calls an action using closure actions and my action is on the route and it gives me this error "ember.debug.js:9418 Uncaught 
EmberError {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: undefined, message: "An action named 'testButton' was not found in <dummy@controller:showcase/x-form::ember737>", name: "Error"…}" because it expecting the action to be on the controller?

Comment: Also would be in route that I would call ember data to save model ?

Comment: `{{x-button label="Test" action=(action "testButton")}}` - Here you are creating closure action which has context of the controller( current template layout context is always controller) so you should define `testButton` action in the controller. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: Right but I thought you were saying to call the action on the route for navigation and manipulating the data?

Comment: For manipulating the data should be done by the owner of the data, in your case I am not sure which one. if its route then route only should change the data. that's best practice. But transitionTo different route , usually will happen in route/controller. if its in route then use `transitionTo` if you are in controller then use `transitionToRoute`. Now with the above mentioned polyfill you can even start transitioning from component. it depends which makes more sense to you.

Comment: To call action on the route you can use [ember-route-action-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) or  read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295604/ember-component-send-action-to-route/42296007#42296007) for more info regarding how to use closure action

Comment: Ok do you know a good full example I can look at the one on the official website barely touch on this?

Comment: Check this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/

Comment: You can follow official tutorial -
 https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/

Comment: Ok what from I get from this example is most of my code related updating/creating/deleting a record should be inside a component and inject the ember-data store this I understand completely using the action up pattern. However how can you call the route without having to define a action on controller? I guess what I am confused is why calling transitionTo on route instead of the controller when you have to call the controller action anyways in order to call the route action?

Comment: `However how can you call the route without having to define a action on controller?` - Its possible only through route-action-helper addon, without you can't achieve it. `why calling transitionTo on route instead of the controller` - This is not rigid rule, you can do it both places thats the reason they provided controllerTo and controllerToRoute method for controller and route repectively. It's matter of taste. Route has `redirect` method and beforeModel/model comes with `transition` object argument which can used for `transition.abort` or `transition.retry()`..

Comment: so if you can see Route has most of the methods related to transition one route to another route. that's the reason its preferrable and also controller is not responsible for doing transition stuff. it's just to decorate the model and its used for updating model and queryParams using actions.

Comment: Ok thanks, that helps clear out some thing we starting a big project soon and I want to make sure we going the right direction. I love Ember but I found since they announced removing the controllers its bit confusing where to put things. If have a route/controller /user-profile is it worth creating user-profile component to do the crud operation or better just to do it in user-profile controller?

Comment: You can very well use controllers.Yes its worth creating user-profile component to display and crud operation should be done in route/controller by passing actions from component actions.

Comment: Ok because on this example you sent they are calling the service directly from the component https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/