# `keyUp` not working, what is the correct way to trigger a keyup on input field

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to integrate a keyup event in my input element. but not works at all. any one help me to showing the correct way to trigger an event?

here is my hbs file:

```
<span class="opt-num">
            <input type="number" tabindex="1" min="0" max="9" maxlength="1" value="" onKeyUp={{action "numberValidate"}} style="border:1px solid red" >

        </span>
```

my route.js file :

```
actions:{

        numberValidate(){ console.log("hi") }
}
```

But getting error as : `Failed: An action named 'numberValidate' was not found`

Answer (score 1):

Template hbs context is controller, so you need to define `numberValidate` function in the actions hash of the controller.

If you want to call router action, then you have two options,
1. Bubble it from controller
define functions controller and from there you need to call functions in route.
In route.js file,

```
actions:{
 numberValidateInRoute(){ console.log("hi") }
}
```

In controller.js file, You need to bubble it using the send method.

```
actions:{
 numberValidate(){ 
   this.send('numberValidateInRoute');
 }
}
```

2. Use [ember-route-action helper addon](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper).

Checkout [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295604/ember-component-send-action-to-route/42296007#42296007) lot more articles related to this topic.

Comment: But I am trying to call the `router` function. what would be the way? same way click funciton ( if i remove keyup ) works fine

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to bubble it from controller to route manually.

Comment: But calling my way `onKeyUp={{action "numberValidate"}}` is correct?

Comment: it's correct as long as you have a handler function in the controller. Since it's not found, nothing handles the action just as @kumkanillam pointed out.

Comment: refer this twiddle https://ember-twiddle.com/294c4d26f6f65f46fe9113f251a92293?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: works fine. the issue is by default it works for `click` so we trying the same way for `keyup` too.. addition question after the user enter a value i would like to focus the next input what is the ember way?

Comment: observe the value of the textbox. when input is correct redirect to the next view.

Comment: By defualt action helper will bind it to click but you can make it to work using `{{action "numberValidate" on="keyup"}}` refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-the-type-of-event. about your second question, you need to write the code to focus the element upon onchange event.

Comment: I agree. the matter is how to I change my focus to next input box, say my input has the class names like `input1`,`input2`.. in jQuery I do like `$input.focus()' by finding class/id names

Comment: How do you know user finished typing the input?

Comment: on key up, will know. as well how to pass the value to function on keyup?

Comment: Go through this updated twiddle which used foucs stuff and how to pass value too..https://ember-twiddle.com/294c4d26f6f65f46fe9113f251a92293?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Comment: You have saved me a day, Just like that!!