# ember js trigger actions on my route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, action

current URL: http://localhost:4200/bands

router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('bands', function(){
        this.route('band', {path: ':slug'}, function(){
          this.route('songs');
          this.route('albums');
      });
    });
});
```

app/routes/bands.js

```
export default Route.extend({
    actions: {
      createBand: function(){
         this.get('controller').set('name', '');
      }
    }
});
```

app/templates/bands.hbs

```
{{input type="text" class="new-band" placeholder="New Band" value=name}}
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm new-band-button" {{action 'createBand'}}>Add</button>
```

It looks like the createBand() function cannot be triggered.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: cannot reproduce: http://jsbin.com/yozegaxevo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Jeff my version is 2.18.0. yours is different.

Comment: still, on 2.16: https://ember-twiddle.com/cfd8262a5314e6fc9e8e14ed25d200c3?numColumns=2&openFiles=routes.bands.js%2Croutes.bands.js

Comment: there must be something else going wrong. did you test a simple console.log in `createBand`?

Comment: @Jeff I recall it said console is not available or something.

Comment: how can console not be available? who said that?

Comment: @Jeff 21:7  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

Comment: @Jeff it is the ember cli

Comment: yes, it will say that when building/serving (coming from [eslint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)). But you can still use it (for development)!

Answer (score 0):

The actions given in the .hbs file are to be implemented in the `controller` but you have implemented them in `route`.
When the action cannot be found in `controller` it goes to its `route`.

Updated the [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/yozegaxevo/1/edit?html,js,output)

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following to make it work:

```
onclick={{action "createBand"}}
```

Comment: You need to define actions `createBand` in actions hash of the bands.js controller and from there you need to call `this.send('createBandInRoutefunction')` you can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296007/5771666)