# Ember action not triggered in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ember.js

This twiddle working in Chrome but not working in firefox

https://ember-twiddle.com/aa8196622fcd6b8f6ce441c8a9174600?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

I found similar issue [here](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader/issues/92), but there is no reason for why it is not working.

I am using Firefox v61.0.1 and Chrome v67.0.3396.99

```
 //application.hbs

 <div class="box">
 <button type="button" class="close note-close" aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true" class="close" {{action 'testAction'}}>&times;</span>
 </button>
 </div>


//application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions: {
    testAction: function() {
      alert("Close Button Working");
    }
  }
});
```

If you click close button in Chrome, It trigger the  testAction in controller. But in firefox there is no error but not trigger my testAction in controller.

Comment: "not working" - the most useless of all problem descriptions - there are no errors, and no indication of anything "not working" - everything looks OK - what's it supposed to do? It does exactly the same level of nothing in both browsers - so you'll have to describe the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a nested element of a button-element does not work.

Add your action to the button-element and use [closure-actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427913/use-closure-actions-unless-you-need-bubbling/48438427#48438427) (onclick)

```html
<button type="button" class="close note-close" aria-label="Close" onclick={{action 'testAction'}}>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="close note-close">&times;</span>
</button>
```