# Ember component call an action in a route or controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a component the main purpose of which is to display a row of items.
Every row has a delete button to make it possible to delete a row. How is possible to pass an action from a template to the component which will trigger an action in a router ?

Here is the template using the component:

```
#templates/holiday-hours.hbs

{{#each model as |holidayHour|}}
  {{holiday-hour holiday=holidayHour shouldDisplayDeleteIcon=true}}
{{/each}}
```

Here is the component template:

```
# templates/components/holiday-hour.hbs
...
div class="col-sm-1">
    {{#if shouldDisplayDeleteIcon}}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1" {{action 'deleteHoliday' holiday}}>
      <span class="oi oi-trash"></span>
    </button>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

I'm using the same component to display a row and to create a new item (`holiday-hour`).

I'm using **ember 3.1.2**

Thank you

Comment: refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296007/5771666) it contains more article which explains clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the actions up from the component to the route. The main way to do this is by adding actions to your component that "send" the action to the parent. Once the action is sent you have to tell the component what action on the route to trigger by passing in the action as a parameter. Below is an example of how to do this.

Component js

```
# components/holiday-hour.js
...
actions: {
   deleteHoliday(){
      this.sendAction('deleteHoliday');
   }
}
```

Template for route

```
#templates/holiday-hours.hbs
...
{{#each model as |holidayHour|}}
  {{holiday-hour holiday=holidayHour shouldDisplayDeleteIcon=true deleteHoliday='deleteHoliday'}}
{{/each}}
```

Route js

```
#routes/holiday-hours.js
...
actions: {
    deleteHoliday(){
        //code to delete holiday
    }
}
```

Comment: as @kimobrian254 put it, see [this aticle](https://emberigniter.com/send-closure-actions-up-data-owner/) explaining `sendAction` use cons and pros.

Comment: I know this is has been posted 2 years ago but thanks! Really clear and working example!

Comment: @feedy this is a rather old answer. It should probably be updated to use closure actions since that is the more proper way to this now.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give a general answer because your question is not giving enough/all info regarding the route actions etc. Long answer short, using closure functions. Assuming this is your route js file `routes/holiday-hours.js`

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(){ /*... some code */ },
    setupController(controller){
        this._super(controller);
        controller.set('actions', {
             passToComponent: function(param) { //.... function logic }
        })
    }
});
```

**Note:** in the above snippet, I'm using `setupController` to create actions. Alternatively, you can put the actions inside a controller file otherwise actions directly inside the route will throw an error.
So I want the action `passToComponent` to be called from the component. This is what you do to make it accessible inside the component.

```
{{#each model as |holidayHour|}}   {{holiday-hour holiday=holidayHour shouldDisplayDeleteIcon=true callAction=(action 'passToComponent')} {{/each}}
```

Now we have passed the action to the component and here's how to call it from the component. Note: I have added a param just to show that it can take a param when called within the component.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    actions: {
       deleteHoliday: ()=> {
         this.get('callAction')() /*Pass in any params in the brackets*/
       }
    }
});
```

You will also see demonstrations using `sendAction` which is rather old and acts more of an event bus that is not very efficient. Read more from this [article](https://emberigniter.com/send-closure-actions-up-data-owner/)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a clear explanation (I'd put it Ember guides). Nevertheless, it seems like I'll have to put the action in the controller: `Assertion Failed: An action named 'deleteHoliday' was not found in <decastore-front@controller`. I put the following in `templates/holiday-hours.hbs`: `{{holiday-hour holiday=holidayHour shouldDisplayDeleteIcon=true deleteAction=(action 'deleteHoliday' holidayHour)}}`. Then in `components/holiday-hour.js`: `deleteHoliday(holiday) {
      this.get('deleteAction')(holiday);
    }`.

Comment: And even if I define the same action `deleteHoliday` as in the route, nothing happens :(.

Comment: I agree the action has to be in the controller or alternatively use `setupController` inside the route. Here's a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c2a4f4c186b278fba2d903899b6b0db4?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs&route=%2Fmy-route) I setup. I'm going to update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put back previously deleted action on the `delete` button in the `templates/componenets/holiday-hour.hbs`: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1"  {{action 'deleteHoliday' holiday}}>`. It works ONLY if I have `deleteHoliday` action defined in `holiday-hours.js` controller.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a note, the action has to be in the controller or inside setupController in the route.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Hope you accept the updated answer as the correct one to help others